# Supervisord Stops Hangs/Hungs on the Background after 10 minutes

Tags: python, linux, centos, centos7, supervisord

Somehow after 10 minutes supervisord stops processing. Processes still on the background but not working anymore. We need to kill the processes first before supervisord starts processing again. Our work around is to add a cron job to kill all supervisord processes every 10 minutes. Is there a way to fix this issue in supervisord so we would not kill processes anymore?

Supervisord version: 3.4.0

Python version: 2.7.5

Centos 7 OS

Answer (score 0):

I found the main problem. In our code we added a $messenger->wait(3600) which turns out to be where process hungs because supervisord is waiting for a return or and exit. What we did was to make the wait lower to 500 and added exit(0) after it. Seems like supervisord in Centos 7 will have an issue if scripts does not do a clear exit. On Centos 6 we did not encounter the issue.